# How can i calculate module of complex number

Tags: c, complex-numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct complex {
    int real, imag;
}complex;


int main ()
{
    int n;
    complex *z;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &z[i].real, &z[i].imag);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int *d;
        d[i]==sqrt((z[i].real*z[i].real)+(z[i].imag*z[i].imag));
        printf("%d\n", d[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to calculate module of input n complex numbers but I don't know how to make the structure and anything else this code give me random value when it compiled.

Comment: C has standard complex number types and functions that act on them...

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex

Comment: `z` does not point anywhere but you dereference it

Comment: You are declaring *d inside a loop, which is useless and is being re-declared in each iteration and also it cannot be used anywhere outside of this loop and the "==" should be a "=" as @TheArcticWalrus said in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are trying to write several numbers into complex `*z` as if it was an array. It is only a pointer to a single complex struct. Try making an array of complex of size n if you want to have several complex numbers. Same thing for int `*d`.

My suggestion would be to get it working for a single complex number first because even without the array problem you are assigning a variable with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Complex {
    int real, imag;
};

int main ()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct Complex z[n];

    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &z[i].real, &z[i].imag);
    }

    double d[n];
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        d[i] = sqrt((z[i].real*z[i].real)+(z[i].imag*z[i].imag));
        printf("%f\n", d[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please Note:

- d[] should be a double-type variable.
- As you already know the number of the inputs, you can declare an
  array of Complex type.
- Avoid using keyword as a variable's or structure's name. You used the
  keyword "complex" as the structure's name.